# Circle background on an input element

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to figure out if this is even possible, from all my research it doesn't appear to be, but I wanted to be 100% sure.

I am trying to draw a circle inside an input element.  The circle would be red colour and then when it passes validation it would turn to green.  I can do this fairly easy using an image, but I am trying to see if I can avoid using images to do this.

I can easily draw circles with divs:

```
<div></div>
div{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
}
```

but I don't know how to draw a circle on a background element.  I was looking into maybe using `:before` or `:after` element but that doesn't seem possible.

Are there any ways of accomplishing this?

Comment: Add a div relative to the input field and draw a circle into it and you need to make the input transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `pseudo-element` and toggle color with `JQuery` on validation (i used `focus` for demo(

```js
$('input').on('focus', function() {
  $(this).parent('div').addClass('active');
});
$('input').on('blur', function() {
  $(this).parent('div').removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}
div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 50%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: blue;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
div.active:before {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using `radial-gradient` background image like in the below snippet. There is no need to add extra elements as long as you have to support only the modern browsers. Pseudo's won't work with `input` element because it is a self-closing tag.

Tested and found to be working fine in Chrome(v51.0.2704.19 dev-m), Firefox (v45.0.2), Opera (v36) Edge, IE11, IE10. [This approach would not work in IE9 and lower because support for CSS gradients is not there in those browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients).

```css
input {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center, red 4px, transparent 5px);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px 100%; /* equal to the height */
  height: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px; /* equal to background-size in X-axis */
}
input:valid {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center, green 4px, transparent 5px);
}
```

```html
<input type='text' required/>
<input type='text' value='Some text' required/>
```

Comment: I am supporting IE9 and up, this doesn't work on IE9, just tested

Comment: @Bagzli: Nope, CSS gradients don't work in IE9. They work only from IE10+. You could either use this approach for IE10+ and use an image fallback for IE9 (or) use a wrapper pseudo-element. I don't think there is any alternate way.